# I want to show gallery in folders view

Tags: android

this is my code which i used is used to show gallery in gridview but shows all pictures in gridview like this

[Sample Link 1](http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&biw=878&bih=598&tbm=isch&tbnid=aE5zGRuSzkvPjM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.photoalbumorganizer.android/Photo-Album-Organizer&docid=j-QCLRmOw4FWxM&imgurl=http://fs02.androidpit.info/ass/x12/276712-1271712590291.jpg&w=480&h=854&ei=h9BbUcbtFI3Qsgav54HoBA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=2&vpy=144&dur=171&hovh=300&hovw=168&tx=62&ty=244&page=2&tbnh=162&tbnw=91&start=19&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:19,s:0,i:136) image but i want to show gallery like this

http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?hl=en&biw=878&bih=598&tbm=isch&tbnid=17fWAXUGZ3USxM:&imgrefurl=http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/sync_your_android_phone_your_mac?page=0,2&docid=FGf7ur67XeENhM&imgurl=http://www.maclife.com/files/u32/1201_videogallery_480.jpg&w=480&h=854&ei=M9FbUY_aNsrvswburIDABw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=664&vpy=144&dur=1467&hovh=300&hovw=168&tx=123&ty=203&page=1&tbnh=135&tbnw=75&start=0&ndsp=19&ved=1t:429,r:18,s:0,i:133

folder view so when user clicks any folder it's content is shown in gridview what do i do?

This is my code.

```
public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
```

`Cursor imagecursor;

int image_column_index;

Button selectBtn;

ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;

DataBase db;

Handler handle = new Handler(){         
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        if (msg.what == 1)
        {
            hideProgress();

            GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById 
   (R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
            imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        }
        else if (msg.what == 3)
        {
            hideProgress();

            AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this.finish();

        }
        else if (msg.what == 2)
        {
            hideProgress();
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);   
    };
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    showProgress();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() { 
             try
            {
                loadFeed();
                android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
                alertMessage.what = 1;
                handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {   
                android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
                alertMessage.what = 2;
                handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);       
            }
        }
    }.start();


    selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            showProgress();
            new Thread() {
                public void run() { 
                     try
                    {
                        SelecedtPhotos();
                        android.os.Message alertMessage = new  
     android.os.Message();
                        alertMessage.what = 3;
                        handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {   
                        android.os.Message alertMessage = new  
    android.os.Message();
                        alertMessage.what = 2;
                        handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);       
                    }
                }
            }.start();


        }
    });

}

public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService 
     (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem,  
  null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView)  
   convertView.findViewById 
 (R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById 
    (R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);

        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();

                if (thumbnailsselection[id])
                {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });

        /*holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" +  
   arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/

        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;

        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}

public void loadFeed()
{
    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,  
  MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

    imagecursor = managedQuery 
   (MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
    columns, null,null, orderBy);

    image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex 
   (MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();

    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];

    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];

    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) 
    {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex 
   (MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail 
 (getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),  
  id,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,  
 null);
        arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }`

Comment: i want to show gallery in folders before gridview and also delect selected files

Answer (score 0):

you know the images which you are going to show in your grid view . so initially get design the custom layout with four images like folder with four image views. then load your particular folder images thumbnails.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: how i do that any example?

Comment: also my code not delte image after copy to application folder